# MVC or CodeIgniter limitation: how I can access a 'sub' controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I don't know if I'm wrong. But all I know is that in MVC, is that the Controllers is always responsible for calculating the data, and the View to print them.

**The problem**

I have a poll that I need use a model to get your data and I use a view to print. Currently I can access this poll by use the url "poll/last". This works fine.

My problem is that I need print this info on some pages (like in "site" controller).

**The Dilemma**

- If I simple load the poll view on page, nothing data is get from model. Onetime that it is work of Controller.
- If I move all controller part to view, this works fine. The low point is that turn the application in a "non-MVC compatible".

**The Solution**

So how can I solve this dilemma?
Actually the CodeIgniter not is a HMVC, and the HMVC module don't works fine -- only locally.

There are some viable solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are not always responsible of all calculations. When those calculations are part o fthe 'business or data model' they should go into the model. My english is not good sometimes but i'll try to explain with an example: Let's say we have a table with persons data, and a column birth_date. Age() function should be in Model, because is another way of seen birth_date.

In your case, I would try to move calc into the model, and write a partial who shows the result, and pass the resulting partial view to the main one. Something like

```
$data['poll_view'] = $this->load->view('poll_partial',$this->poll_model->getPollData(),true);
$this->load->view('current_view', $data ); //that includes poll subview
```

Comment: But I really can executes a Model on a View? The MVC Diagram don't show that. It's more compatible with I want (but is Joomla) http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Joomla_mvc-diagram.png

Comment: As I understand, no, a View shouldn't access a model. But you can build your view by parts, using partials, built in the controller. I'll try to edit my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, forgive me if I'm wrong.  I can't comment yet on posts, so consider that this **may be** an answer.

You're wanting to use the data that is in the poll/last controller in another one?

Why not have the same code that you're doing on the controller, in a method/function in the model?

That way, when you call your model just like in the poll controller, the same code and data is available to the site controller.

That's the main function of models.

In my opinion it goes like this:

**View** - Displays the data, formats the data, and puts the data where you want it.
**Controller** - Takes the data and determines what exactly to show and on what URL / location to show it, and in which view.
**Model** - Gets the data from the database, does any calculations that you need to, and returns it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Models need calculate only data baseed on this model. Controller can do everything. Theorically, views can't access directly a model data (only controllers). So your suggestion is not MVC compatible, I think. But thanks for help :)

Comment: Technically I do believe a view can access model data?  If we're using an ActiveRecord based model.. such as Post.. we pass an array of Post objects to the View.. the view sorts through them with a foreach, so technically it can access model data?

Comment: You can load model data on controller and pass to a view, but theorically, you can't load model data directly on view.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to load the poll view into other views?  If so, take a look here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/189935/

The same question has been asked/answered

Forgive me if that wasn't your question... can't comment on posts...

Comment: Is basically that. But I need do all in controller, what is a big problem is too confusous if you need to load too many 'components' (poll, ads, news, top members...)